# WordPress - How do I remove meta generator tags?

Tags: wordpress, meta-tags

I have these tags:

```
<meta name="generator" content="Woo Framework Version 3.1.1" />
<meta name="generator" content="WordPress 3.5" />
<meta name="generator" content="Canvas 3.0" />
```

I understand to remove the WordPress version tag I add:

```
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'wp_generator' ); // goes into functions.php
```

But how do I remove the themes `meta` tags?

Answer (score 31):

If you are trying only to remove the `meta="generator"` add this line to your ***functions.php***.

```
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'wp_generator' );
```

Comment: That only removes the line with the WordPress version.

Answer (score 22):

Was looking for a solution for removing Layer Slider meta generator, didn't find much help on any of the handful of websites I looked at, they are all sharing the same info, which only pertains to either **WordPress** generator or popular plugins like **WooCommerce**.

The problem here is that every plugin is going to have it's own hook names and naming conventions, so to learn or know them all will be nearly impossible. The easiest way I think is plain PHP with `preg_replace`.

Working code that has been tested in **WordPress 6.5**.
Inside functions.php of your theme drop in this code and it should work.

```
//Remove All Meta Generators
ini_set('output_buffering', 'on'); // turns on output_buffering
function remove_meta_generators($html) {
    $pattern = '/<meta name(.*)"generator"[^>]*>/i';
    $html = preg_replace($pattern, '', $html);
    return $html;
}
function clean_meta_generators($html) {
    ob_start('remove_meta_generators');
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'clean_meta_generators', 100);
add_action('wp_footer', function(){ ob_end_flush(); }, 100);
```

I am using regular expression to capture the `meta` tag. It covers whether they put spaces in between the equals sign or not. Using `ob_start` to cover the whole document. So we add the `preg_replace` starting at the header all the way to the footer. See how `ob_start` works in the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php), also there are times [WordPress codex](https://codex.wordpress.org) does states it should be using `ob_start`.

If you find this useful please add a thumbs up so the next person looking can land on a working solution that covers all meta generators. I feel it's bad security for these plugin and platform developers to put meta generator version numbers in the code. Especially with evolving vulnerabilities being discovered all the time.

Ive also added a plugin that does this exact thing on the **WordPress repository**.

[Remove Meta Generators](https://wordpress.org/plugins/remove-meta-generators/)

Comment: This will not necessarily work on all themes. I've found that kjy112 's answer below is more likely to be the correct answer. (I tested on WP 4.9.6 with various themes, but without WooCommerce.)

Comment: This should work on all themes. All themes have a header and a footer and the code provided just uses plain php regular expression to strip out the meta generator tags. If you are having an issue with the code it could be a server issue with ob_start configurations. What errors are you getting when you say it "will not necessarily work on all themes"?

Comment: There are no errors; it just didn't work on a couple of my test sites.  I found that the answer from @kjy112 worked in all of my test sites.

Comment: Do you have debug enabled? Sometimes there are error messages but are being suppressed. Also curious are these custom themes or can you send a link to one of them. This code again is just using pure PHP for stripping out meta generator tags, it should work on pretty much all themes unless there is a server issue.

Comment: Output buffering I think was your issue. If you add this line of code should do the trick. ini_set('output_buffering', 'on'); // turns on output_buffering

Comment: Be careful, if the <meta> tag is followed by another tag (in my case it was a <script>) but when it isn't on another line, it removes the next opening tag (again, in my case a <script>) as well.

Answer (score 5):

At the bottom of the **functions.php** file add this following php snippet:

```
// hide the meta tag generator from head and rss
function disable_version() {
   return '';
}
add_filter('the_generator','disable_version');
remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_generator');
```

Answer (score 5):

I recently ran into this issue, and had to remove the meta tags for security and spam reasons for a client.  I was able to remove Wordpress's meta generator but the theme uses woo framework so using

```
remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_generator');
```

Is not sufficient. To remove

```
<meta name="generator" content="Woo Framework Version x.x.x" />
```

and anything any meta generator tags that your theme generates simply add this line to the end of your template's functions.php

```
// remove the unwanted <meta> links
remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_generator');
remove_action('wp_head', 'woo_version');
```

This worked for me on Woo Framework 5.5.5.  To locate where the generator meta tag is initialized, look for your `admin-init.php` file for your template and `woo_version()` function and `woo_version_init()` function should be there.  Usually its under the includes folder within your theme source.

Comment: This didn't remove the `<meta name="generator" content="Site Kit by Google 1.123.1" />` tag, from Google Site Kit, for me.

Answer (score 3):

I found [this](https://gist.github.com/leekelleher/4593646)  source code of a plugin which states that it removes the auto-generated WP meta tags. You could try that.

- Plugin Name: Remove WP Meta
- Plugin URI: http://leekelleher.com/
- Description: This plugin removes the auto-generated WP meta tags from each webpage.
- Author: Lee Kelleher

Comment: Thanks! I've tried it with WP 4.0 and it works perfect.

Comment: Link-only solutions are no good.  If the link breaks, it's useless.  Provide the name of the plugin, and / or the relevant code here.

Comment: You are correct. I just added more information taken from the plugin comment section. Luckily the link was still working or otherwise I would not have known what plugin I suggested :)

Comment: FYI that method does not remove version numbers from e.g. RSS feeds, so disabling the entire function is considered better practice.

Answer (score 3):

## NO!

In case if it is hardcoded into your theme's template (i.e. in header.php),then you have to manually remove that!

Otherwise, use this full solution, to remove all version tags:

```
// ============ removing inbuilt WP meta-tag ===========  http://stackoverflow.com/q/16335347/2377343  ========== //
  //if included in wp_head
    add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'my_wp_version_remover' ); function my_wp_version_remover(){
        remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_generator'); 
    }
  //clean all responses from VERSION GENERATOR
    add_filter('the_generator',             'rm_generator_filter'); 
    add_filter('get_the_generator_html',    'rm_generator_filter');
    add_filter('get_the_generator_xhtml',   'rm_generator_filter');
    add_filter('get_the_generator_atom',    'rm_generator_filter');
    add_filter('get_the_generator_rss2',    'rm_generator_filter');
    add_filter('get_the_generator_comment', 'rm_generator_filter');
    add_filter('get_the_generator_export',  'rm_generator_filter');
    add_filter('wf_disable_generator_tags', 'rm_generator_filter');
                                    function rm_generator_filter() {return '';}
// ========================================================== //
```

Comment: Man, this is a sledgehammer.  It includes stuff to remove version parameters, which is not relevant to the question....

Answer (score 2):

This one finds the sitekit by Google, but can be modified for anything. Thanks to [this article](https://www.valendigital.co.uk/blog/remove-meta-namegenerator-contentwordpress-x-x-1/) and his [plugin](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/meta-generator-and-version-info-remover/).

```
add_action('get_header',function (){
    ob_start(function ($o) {
        return preg_replace('/\n?<.*?content="Site Kit by Google.*?>/mi','',$o);
    });
});
add_action('wp_head',function (){
    ob_end_flush();
   }, 992);
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code gets rid of all generator tags in the Woo Framework. I have tested it with Woo Framework 6.0.4 and the theme Canvas 5.8.3:

```
// Remove the WooThemes version from the html headers
function no_woo_version ()
{
   return true;
}
add_filter ('wf_disable_generator_tags', 'no_woo_version');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you made your ouw custom WordPress theme, there will be no problem with generator  in meta, DO like i Did in samll sample. There will be no generator, if you will not declare it like some of your custom functions. I try to control all JS scripts and Styles of my theme [like here](http://sierra-group.in.ua/start-legkogo-rezhima-preprocesornoj-sborki-vashih-fajlov-stilej-i-skriptov.html/#custom-register-styles-sctiprs).
If i have, style from plugins, there some more Job needed.

but if you use, free theme, yes in 100% there will be generator.
So add in File Function.php  [1](http://sierra-group.in.ua/start-legkogo-rezhima-preprocesornoj-sborki-vashih-fajlov-stilej-i-skriptov.html/#custom-register-styles-sctiprs): http://sierra-group.in.ua/start-legkogo-rezhima-preprocesornoj-sborki-vashih-fajlov-stilej-i-skriptov.html/#custom-register-styles-sctiprs

```
function disable_version() { return '';}
add_filter('the_generator','disable_version');
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'wp_generator');
remove_action('wp_head', 'woo_version'); 
function no_woo_version (){   return true;}
add_filter ('wf_disable_generator_tags', 'no_woo_version');
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
/* You can use the the_generator filter to disable the meta generator tag. You’ll need to add the code below to the functions.php file of your theme*/

If you want to remove the generator XML or Comment for RSS, ATOM, etc used below the wordpress hook


add_filter( 'the_generator', '__return_null' );
```