# Hiding Wordpress version using wp_generator

Tags: php, wordpress

I've tried to remove the generator meta from a wordpress 5.6 installation but it will fail. I've added this hook to my functions.php file (also in child theme that is active) but without success

```
remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_generator');
```

What I've missed out?Is there any change in wp 5.6 api that will break this hook?Can be the issue caused from caching plugins like jetpack?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16335347/wordpress-how-do-i-remove-meta-generator-tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use, as an alternative, the `the_generator()` function through a filter.

> ### `the_generator( string $type )`
>
> Display the generator XML or Comment for RSS, ATOM, etc.

| Parameters | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `$type` | (string) (Required) The type of generator to output (html/xhtml/atom/rss2/rdf/comment/export) |

- Source @ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_generator/

The following should hide the generator meta `<meta name="generator" content="WordPress 5.6" />`

```
add_filter( 'the_generator', function() {
  return;
} );
```

Keep in mind that the version is also appended to each Wordpress core script. You can add the following to hide the version.

```
<?php
$filters = [
  'style_loader_src',
  'script_loader_src',
];
foreach ( $filters as $filter ) {
  add_filter( $filter, function( $src ) {
    if( strpos( $src, '?ver=' ) )
      $src = remove_query_arg( 'ver', $src );
    return $src;
  } );
}; ?>
```

> PHP > 7.1 required, [Anonymous function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) used in example

Comment: ok,I will try with the filter you've suggested. In old wordpress versions the `remove_action` was working fine, is this a modification of last wp releases?

Comment: Unrelated to 5.6.

Comment: so why `remove_action` won't work? I saw a lot of guides online that use this remove action without problems

Comment: It's working on my end. On Wordrpess latest `5.6`. @ https://wordpress.org/download/

Comment: I don't know what can be tha cause that will make the action not working on my wordpress installation. Maybe there is a plugin or a theme that will cause the problem.